# Not able to pass parameter to telerik report which is using ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am new to telerik reporting and I created simple report in ASP.Net MVC 4 which use ObjectDataSource. I created one model class like below

```
[DataObject]
public class StockMonitoring
{

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public List<StockDetail> GetExpiredDrugBrand(int SiteID)
    {
        //returns list by calling stored procedure which takes SiteID
    }
}
```

In controller I am using this code:

```
using Telerik.Reporting;
..........
............
TypeReportSource Source = new TypeReportSource();
Source.TypeName = typeof(StockMonitoring_Expired).AssemblyQualifiedName;
Source.Parameters.Add(new Parameter("SiteID", SID));
ViewBag.ReportSource = Source;
```

and In view following code:

```
 @(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()    
   .Id("reportViewer1")
   .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
   .TemplateUrl("/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-8.1.14.804.html")
   .ReportSource((ReportSource) ViewBag.ReportSource)
   .ViewMode(ViewModes.INTERACTIVE)
   .ScaleMode(ScaleModes.SPECIFIC)
   .Scale(1.0)
   .PersistSession(false)
   )
```

When I comment this line

```
    Source.Parameters.Add(new Parameter("SiteID", SID));
```

and set design time value for SiteID in my report "StockMonitoring_Expired" which is created in VS 2012 my above code works properly and break point hit "GetExpiredDrugBrand" method in model but when I uncomment above line and remove design time value for SiteID my code give below error:

```
An error has occurred while processing Table 'table1': An error has occurred while resolving 'ObjectDataSource' data source: Cannot convert to type System.Int32
```

I am not able to pass SiteID parameter to my "GetExpiredDrugBrand" method which in turn called stored procedure to retrive data. I read telerik reporting documentation but not able to figure out problem. What's wrong in code?

Thank you in advance......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution of it. While designing report I forgot to add parameter to use. I follow this link for adding parameter http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-parameters-adding-parameters.html and my problem solved.